# Reference a file in Unit Test (VB.Net 2012)

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing

I'm really puzzled on this one.

I an writing unit tests for a project. I need to open and use a file for the testing. I am developing in two environments (work and home) and am using Dropbox to keep my code to be able to use the most recent version at either place.

I have created the test file and have placed it in a folder in the Unit Test project. I could obviously use the file spec

> c:\blah\blah\blah\file.txt

but that would only work on one machine.

So my question is...
Is there a value/parameter/Constant that I could use in my test code that would have the root of the project regardless of which location I am at. I want to be able to reference the file like so:

> {projectRoot}\folder\file.txt

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path to the folder in which the current executable resides, like this:

```
Dim exeFolderPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
```

Or:

```
Dim exeFolderPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()(0))
```

Or, if you are in a DLL, and you need to get the path to the folder containing that DLL, instead of the executable that is using it, you can do this:

```
Dim assemblyFolderPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Alternatively, you can just use the current folder, like this:

```
Dim currentFolderPath As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

Then you can drill down to a sub-folder, like this:

```
Dim subFolderPath = Path.Combine(exeFolderPath, subFolderName)
```

In order to make it so that the text file, which is included in your project, exists in the output binary folder, just select the file in the *Solution Explorer*, go to the properties window and change the *Copy to Output Directory* setting to either *Copy always* or *Copy if newer*.  Then, when you build your project, the file will automatically get copied to the appropriate bin folder.